# Accidentally deleted code inside home.php file ony my wordpress app how to restore it

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using One Page wordpress theme and inside home.php i accidentally removed some code and inside wordpress there is no undo button  ( dunno why ) so how can I rewrite it so it works or somehow return it back

this is my code right now

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
get_header();
?>
/* HERE DELETED SOME STUFF NOW CANT RETURN IT */
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Re-download the theme and upload a fresh copy. This is why you need backups.

Comment: you could also look in your backups, your versioning repo, the local history of your IDE.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I suspect OP used the (dangerous, IMO) in-WordPress textarea file editor. Doubt there's a repo or an IDE involved.

Comment: @ceejayoz argh ... thanks for clarifying that. I steer clear from such `? frameworks ?` most of the time (with good reasons). Completely forgot that aspect of them.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Yeah, me too these days. Making server's files writeable by webserver from an often-vulnerable PHP script is not my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download the theme (from https://wordpress.org/themes/one-page/) and look in the home.php file this is what it contains:

```
<?php
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
get_header();
?>
<!--Including sliders section -->
<?php echo get_template_part( 'templates/homepage', 'sliders' ); ?>
<!--/Including sliders section -->
<?php
onepage_section_show();
?>
<?php
get_footer();
```